# Can enemies see my phasewalk?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

As an Jedi Shadow I got the ability `Phase Walk`.

I can place the ability on the ground  and it leaves a marker. I can run away from it, and when I use the ability I get transported to that marker.  If I spec tank it places a larger mark on the ground which gives a healing buff.

My question, are enemies able to see the marker I place on the ground?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes.**  I just tested this in my Stronghold with an opposite-faction player.  We could both see each other's Phase Walk marker (both the DPS dot and the Tank circle), whether flagged/dueling or not.